# Removing a string prefix

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string

I have a string of numbers that I need to trim a portion from using TSQL.

The string of numbers will always start with `101` then it will have a set of `0s` and a set of random numbers. Example:

```
1010000123456
```

I need to trim the 101 and the set of zeros.  This is probably simple but I'm having all kinds of issues because I don't have a specific character to reference to using a `CHARINDEX` and the possible combination of a `001` when the random numbers start that I need to keep is giving me issues using a `PATINDEX` with a `SUBSTRING`.

Comment: Remove the first 3 characters and then use `PATINDEX()`.

Comment: This would work I think: `SELECT SUBSTRING(n, 3+PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(n, 4, LEN(n))), LEN(n))` (where `n` is the string.)

Comment: The string will always be 13 digits.  It seems to be working in my query now.

Comment: @PaulWhite Yes there will always be more than one zero but it's random based on how long the following set of [1-9] numbers are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `SUBSTRING(n, 3+PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(n, 4, LEN(n))), LEN(n))` expression should work.

- first, it strips the first 3 characters: `SUBSTRING(n, 4, LEN(n))`
- then it use `PATINDEX()` with the `'%[^0]%'` pattern to locate where the digits after the 0s start: `PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(n, 4, LEN(n)))`
- then it uses `SUBSTRING()` and the previously found number (+3), to keep only the wanted digits (from the patindex number found up to the end.)

Test at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/37425)

Answer (score 3):

There are other ways to do it, eg [STUFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188043.aspx) or just some simple integer maths, but these do make certain assumptions about the string, eg

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, yourString CHAR(13) )

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    ( 1010000123456 ),
    ( 1010001234567 ),
    ( 1010012345678 ),
    ( 1010123456789 ),
    ( 1011234567890 )

SELECT
    CAST( STUFF( yourString, 1, 3, 0 )  AS INT ) [stuff],   -- 2 functions
    CAST( yourString  AS BIGINT ) - 1010000000000 do_math,  -- 1 function
    SUBSTRING(yourString, 3+PATINDEX('%[^0]%', SUBSTRING(yourString, 4, LEN(yourString))), LEN(yourString)) AS ypercube     -- 5 functions
FROM @t
```

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness, you could use the following:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( rowId INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, yourString CHAR(13) )

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
    ( 1010000123456 ),
    ( 1010001234567 ),
    ( 1010012345678 ),
    ( 1010123456789 ),
    ( 1011234567890 )

SELECT CAST(RIGHT(yourString, LEN(yourString)-3) AS BIGINT)
FROM @t;
```

This presumes you *always* have a string that is at least 3 characters long, and removes the left-most 3 characters, turning the remaining string into a BIGINT to remove the leading zeros.

props to @wBob for providing the DDL.